# Linux: UDP receive message slower than that is send out

Tags: c, linux, sockets, udp

I am using a arm-cpu based board, running a uclinux with kernel Linux version 2.6.12.3-a9-17 to receive data from a PC by eithernet, using UDP protocol.

My problem is, on the board, although I can receive all the messages (no lost), the time interval between incoming messages is limited to 20ms at most. That is, if I send out messages every 30ms, everything is OK. However, if I send out message every 10ms, the board shows incoming UDP package every 20ms ( So it will take twice the time that PC use to receive all the messages).

I am using these code to measure the time interval between two incoming message:

```
struct timeval tnew, told, dt;
gettimeofday(&tnew,0);
told = tnew;

while (1) {
    memset(buf, 100, 0);
    int recvlen = recvfrom(fd, buf, 100 , 0,
                           (struct sockaddr *)&addr_recv, &addr_len);
    if (recvlen>0) {
        gettimeofday(&tnew ,0);
        timersub(&tnew,&told,&dt);
        told = tnew;
        printf("UDP intput: %fms, string:%s\n", (float)dt.tv_usec / 1000.0,buf);
    }
```

Here is the result:

on PC:

```
UDP output: 10.019000ms, string: 353:ABCDEFG
UDP output: 10.067000ms, string: 354:ABCDEFG
UDP output: 10.068000ms, string: 355:ABCDEFG
UDP output: 10.068000ms, string: 356:ABCDEFG
UDP output: 10.004000ms, string: 357:ABCDEFG
UDP output: 10.120000ms, string: 358:ABCDEFG
```

on board:

```
UDP intput: 20.000000ms, string: 353:ABCDEFG, 
UDP intput: 20.002000ms, string: 354:ABCDEFG, 
UDP intput: 19.998000ms, string: 355:ABCDEFG, 
UDP intput: 20.051000ms, string: 356:ABCDEFG, 
UDP intput: 19.953000ms, string: 357:ABCDEFG, 
UDP intput: 19.996000ms, string: 358:ABCDEFG,
```

I think this interval should be defined by something in the linux system. How can I fix it?

Btw, iptables of the board shows (EXT = eth0):

```
 iptables -A INPUT -i $EXT -p udp -d 0/0 --dport 1024:65535 -j ACCEPT
```

Thank you very much.

Comment: You can read about how [TCP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transmission_Control_Protocol) handles the very same problem, with [sliding windows](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sliding_window_protocol).

Comment: Just a guess. Have you tried to increase receiving process priority? Try RT priority.

Comment: How long does it take for the board to output the printf string?  Does it have a fast video controller or a slow serial link?

Comment: @MartinJames: by ssh, printf use 0.4ms, by serial port, i redirected the output to a file and printf use 0.17ms.

Comment: @Marian I tried renice it to -20 but problem remained

Comment: @JoachimPileborg the problem will occur even if there is only one byte sent out at each time, and my app is sensitive to receiving frequency therefore as my understanding to sliding windows it does not work to me.

Comment: Do you have access to the UDP driver code ? This sounds like there is a check for received data every 20ms (which may be fine), but it stops after one packet instead of handling all the pending packets.

Comment: @ElderBug 'check for received data every 20ms (which may be fine)' - sounds like suckage to me:)

Comment: I still suspect process scheduling. You have 2 system calls and your loop is executed each 20ms even when there are datagrams waiting in the system buffer. Could you put another gettimeofday somewhere into the loop and to see if the time increases to 30ms?

Comment: @Marian When I tried to get the time consumed by printf, I inserted another pair of gettimeofday just before and after the printf function. The result was something like (20ms,udp) (0.4ms printf). Btw I tested the receiver on another PC in ubuntu. It gave out 10ms correctly.

Comment: Yeah, I'm betting on @ElderBug suggestion; 'crap driver'

Answer (score 0):

thank you for your kind replies. I found out the problem is due to a usleep(10) and the end of while. On the board, usleep(10) takes exactly 20ms, while on another PC it takes 0.1ms.